# Mongo Project _id of Array of Documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I struggle writing Mongo Queries. I can never understand why it doesn't return what I expect and yes I am reading the documentation but apparently to dumb to understand.

In Compass I write this query for a State collection with a document array of cities.

{"Cities.CityName":"Denver"}

This returns to me the State of Colorado document with ALL the cities in the document array. My sample below just shows one city document but they are all there.

```
{
"_id": {"$oid":"6146ada531696ee91a3f9fa4"},
"StateName": "Colorado",
"StateCode": "CO",
"Cities": [{
    "_id": {"$oid":"6146ada531696ee91a3f5a50"},
    "CityName": "Denver",
    "Latitude": "39.55666000",
    "Longitude": "-104.89609000"
    }...]
}
```

OK so I'm thinking clearly we matched on the CityName now just project the _id of the City document.

{"Cities._id":1}

But this always returns to me the State document id NOT the matched City Document _id.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### 1) You can use [$ (projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) or [$elemMatch (projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/):

- **use case:** The positional $ operator limits the contents of an `<array>` to return the first element that matches the query condition on the array.
- **ex:**
  `{ "Cities.$": 1 }` or ​`{"Cities": { "$elemMatch": { "CityName": "Denver" } } }`
- **result:**

```
{
 ​"_id":{"$oid":"6146ada531696ee91a3f9fa4"},
 ​"Cities":[{
   ​"_id":{"$oid":"6146ada531696ee91a3f5a50"},
   ​"CityName":"Denver",
   ​"Latitude":"39.55666000",
   ​"Longitude":"-104.89609000"
 ​}]
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-7WyZgHqXOD)

> **Note:** You have to specify the required result fields in the projection!

##### 2) You can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation operator, supported from MongoDB 4.4 in `find()` method:

- **use case:** Selects a subset of an array to return based on the specified condition. Returns an array with only those elements that match the condition. The returned elements are in the original order.
- **ex:**

```
{ 
  "Cities": { 
    "$filter": { 
      "input": "$Cities", 
      "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.CityName", "Denver"] } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

- **result:**

```
{
 ​"_id":{"$oid":"6146ada531696ee91a3f9fa4"},
 ​"Cities":[{
   ​"_id":{"$oid":"6146ada531696ee91a3f5a50"},
   ​"CityName":"Denver",
   ​"Latitude":"39.55666000",
   ​"Longitude":"-104.89609000"
 ​}...{}]
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/om8pJRGPxbM)

> **Note:** You have to specify the required result fields in the projection!

##### 2.1) You can use `$map` aggregation operator to select only `_id`s from the `Cities` array:

- **use case:** Applies an expression to each item in an array and returns an array with the applied results.
- **ex:**

```
{ 
  "Cities": { 
    "$map": {
      "input": {
        "$filter": { 
          "input": "$Cities", 
          "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.CityName", "Denver"] } 
        }
      },
      "in": "$$this._id"
    }
  } 
}
```

- **result:**

```
{
  "_id":{"$oid":"6146ada531696ee91a3f9fa4"},
  "Cities":[
    {"$oid":"6146ada531696ee91a3f5a50"},
    {"$oid":"6146ada531696ee91a3f5a51"},
    ....
  ]
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4Y7dYiYfYi3)

> **Note:** You have to specify the required result fields in the projection!

##### 3) You can use aggregation method [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/) for more customization:

**- ex:**

- `$match` to check query condition
- `$addFields` to add or format the existing properties
- `$filter` and $map i have explained in 2) point

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "Cities.CityName": "Denver" } },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "Cities": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$Cities",
              "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.CityName", "Denver"] }
            }
          },
          "in": "$$this._id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7Fp_sNgUR1L)

- **result:**

```
[
  {
    "Cities": [
      ObjectId("6146ada531696ee91a3f5a50")
    ],
    "StateCode": "CO",
    "StateName": "Colorado",
    "_id": ObjectId("6146ada531696ee91a3f9fa4")
  }
]
```

Comment: This was what I needed. Thank You. 

It just seems so simple in t-sql but that's probably because I'm used to joining multiple tables. I'm sure after completing a couple mongo courses on Pluralsight / Udemy and practice it'll seem just as straight forward.